# Why object`s colour changes when i play with roughness?

Tags: materials

I have to make this object glossy, the problem is when i turn down the roughness it becomes half black, the original colour is blue.[image] 
I will upload photos to explain.
enter image description here

Comment: do you have an environment map active? If you are reflecting pure darkness its kind of obvious that thats black

Comment: Yes i have Environment active instead of using Lamps.

Comment: BUt if i use any light source it remains black.

Comment: are your Normals facing out? Press Ctrl+N in Editmode to fix that

Comment: This problems occurs when i smooth the object, i pressed flat now and material works good., But i need to keep it smooth.

Comment: did you try fixing Normals?